# If pathname contains....load specific iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, pathname

I am trying to find a way to load a specific iframe depending on if there is a longer pathname provided, i need one that will load if the pathname is normal (i.e doesn't have an extra search at the end) and then load another iframe if the search equals to a specific url i have, so far i have came up with the following but am unsure where to go next/how to then load the specific iframe? Any help appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
 if(pathname.indexOf('#this needs to be empty?') > -1){
 >>>>>load first iframe
 }
```

});

```
 $(document).ready(function(){         
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
 if(pathname.indexOf('?thisismysearchpath') > -1){
 >>>>load second iframe
 }
```

});

Comment: What's wrong with your example? Error?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the iframes in the DOM, you just need to set their `src` attribute like this:

`document.getElementById('frame1').src = 'someurl';`